# Logout JSF, using SSL in Glassfish 3

Tags: jsf, logout

I havent found a real solution for this problem, even when it is really common...

I have this context:

- JSF application running on Glassfish Server v3.1, JDK6. All in my personal computer with WinVista (This last should not be important).
- Using SSL and Basic authentication (Security of the container)
- I have done my logout() method in my backing bean invalidating the session and sending a redirect.

I can not make the container show again the Login box to validate the user, and be able to change of user... And my user always can go back, pressing the BACK button in the browser or just writing the URL, and continue doing thnigs there when is supposed that there should not be a existing session.

I am getting the name of the user the my backing bean is created:

```
private void setName() {
    this.name = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getUserPrincipal().getName();

}
```

And I use this name to perform operations...

Then for logout my xhtml has the code:

```
        <h:panelGroup id="logOut">
        <h:form>
            <h:commandLink id="linkLogOut" action="#{visitor.logout}" value="  Clic here to Log Out" />
        </h:form>
    </h:panelGroup>
```

That calls this method in my bean::

```
public void logout() throws IOException {
   // FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().invalidateSession();
    this.name = null;
    FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    HttpSession session = (HttpSession)fc.getExternalContext().getSession(false);
    session.invalidate();
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("https://localhost:8080/");
}
```

I am declaring my backing bean with:

```
@Named(value="visitor")
@SessionScoped
```

...Also I was doing the redirect from the the deployment descriptor... and it was the same.

If I close the browser the the session is lost and the container ask me again for user/pass.

Any suggestions?

Thanks a lot!

Alejandro.

Answer (score 0):

> *I can not make the container show again the Login box to validate the user, and be able to change of user... And my user always can go back, pressing the BACK button in the browser or just writing the URL, and continue doing thnigs there when is supposed that there should not be a existing session.*

Those pages are likely displayed from the browser cache rather than re-requested from the server. To stop this, create a [`Filter`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html) which is mapped on URL pattern of interest (`*.jsf` maybe?) and does the following job in `doFilter()` method:

```
HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
httpResponse.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache,no-store,must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1
httpResponse.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0
httpResponse.setDateHeader("Expires", 0); // Proxies.
chain.doFilter(request, response);
```

Clear the browser cache before testing.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for all your answers.

I took some days off... and did not reply this thread.

I just want to share my solution.

Basic authentication is bound to the browser, and once you have done login, should should close the browser to finish the logoff... what is not so elegant.

I changed to FORM authentication, creating my form, and posting the user information to a servlet who validates the user credentials against my realm, and this servlet redirect the user to either the application or to an error page. Obviously the proper configuration ifor security-constrain in web.xml have to be done.

I am sharing my solution here:

Login page:

```
<!-- This is the login page that implement the "Form Base" login -->
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
<h:head>
    <title>Login Form</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h2>Welcome to the secure messaging service!:</h2>
    <form name="loginForm" method="POST" action="j_security_check">
        <p><strong>Please type your user name: </strong>
            <input type="text" name="j_username" size="25" /></p>
        <p><strong>Please type your password: </strong>
            <input type="password" size="15" name="j_password" /></p>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
            <input type="reset" value="Reset"/>
        </p>
    </form>
</h:body>
```

My validation servlet method:

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
throws ServletException, IOException {
try {
        String username;
        String password;
        username = request.getParameter("j_username").toString();
        password = request.getParameter("j_password").toString();
        request.login(username, password);
        response.sendRedirect("/SecureMessageWebInterface/");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        response.sendRedirect("error.xhtml");
    }           
}
```

And the required part of the configuration file....

```
<security-constraint>
    <display-name>Web Interface</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>SSL Pages</web-resource-name>
        <description/>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <description>All site is restricted</description>
        <role-name>user</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <description>Secure connection is required</description>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <realm-name>webapps</realm-name>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/login.xhtml</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/error.xhtml</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>
```

I hope this can be useful for someone else.

All the best,

Alejandro.